# C# contextmenustrip doesn't show any indication if any item is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem

I have added a context menu strip 'View' on my listview with some menu items, like Large icons/ Small icons/ Tiles.

Now whenever I select any of the options the respective view changes, but the menu doesn't get any Mark/ indication like that happens in Windows file explorer, where it shows bullet/ dot against the selected menu item.

Can someone please show, how I can get the similar dot/ bullet for my context menu?

I have tried CheckOnClick property which gets me a tick mark, but is there any other way that I could get that dot there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get bullets/ dots like Windows File Explored's View options, but I used below logic and used checked states to indicate the selections made.

```
 private void toolStripViewOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            ToolStripMenuItem selectedOption = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

            SetIndicationForSelectedOption(selectedOption);
 }



private void SetIndicationForSelectedOption(ToolStripMenuItem selectedMenuItem)
{
            ToolStripItemCollection menuItems = (contextMenuStrip.Items[(Int32)toolStripView.Tag] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems;

            // Set checked state for only the selected view option and disable same for others.
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuItems)
            {
                if (selectedMenuItem == item)
                    selectedMenuItem.Checked = true;
                else
                    item.Checked = false;
            }
 }
```

This worked for my requirement.